# Permissions for signing through Google KMS API

Tags: google-cloud-kms

I have number of applications running in GCP and using KMS to sign certificates. I give each application sign permission (projects.locations.keyRings.cryptoKeys.cryptoKeyVersions.asymmetricSign) for specific key. In order to sign I need to provide specific key version (actually I want to use the last version of the key), so I have to get list of version for the key and this requires projects.locations.keyRings.cryptoKeys.get or projects.locations.keyRings.cryptoKeys.cryptoKeyVersions.list permission.

The question is why I need to give this permission to sign a certificate and whether there is way to sign without getting list of versions.

Comment: Why do you need to list versions to get the ID? You should be able to pass in the full CryptoKeyVersion path to your application and then call sign/verify directly without auxiliary lookups. If you want to use “latest” then you need “list” permissions. You shouldn’t need “get” permissions though, since you just need the key version ID

Comment: But how I know version id? The key name is known by application but version id is not. The version is rotated externally to application.

Comment: You can remember the version id when you create a key version and thus record your intended version elsewhere. The reason we didn't support automatic rotation and an "active" or "latest" version in KMS is because you generally need your public key to be certified or conveyed to the consumer; since we can't control that validity step, we didn't think "active" was useful. If you are signing certificates, you probably know the public key of the signing key you wish to use; record the version for the associated private key alongside and you can sign without list privileges.